# Fatal error: Class 'Snipe\BanBuilder\CensorWords' not found

Tags: php, composer-php

i'm working to implement [BanBuilder](http://banbuilder.com/) in my project with composer.
I follow the step in the official site for installing and implementing the script to work by adding the following lines:

```
use Snipe\BanBuilder\CensorWords;
$censor = new CensorWords;
$string = $censor->censorString($mystring);
```

But when i test it i got this error: 
**Fatal error: Class 'Snipe\BanBuilder\CensorWords' not found...**
I tried to declare the function directly without 'use' `$ censor = new Snipe\BanBuilder\CensorWords;` But i get the same problem too.

So what is the cause of this problem and how can i solve it.
This is a screenshot for BanBuilder package in my project:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0DGJ.jpg

The namespace in CensorWords is: `namespace Snipe\BanBuilder;`

Comment: Have you included the composer autoload? I mean, in you project do `require __DIR__ . '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'`?

Comment: Thank you @XicoXperto i forgot this step, now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file where the class CensorWords is located have the correct namespace?

```
namespace Snipe\BanBuilder;
```

Comment: The namespace in CensorWords.php is: `namespace Snipe\BanBuilder;`

Comment: Change file structure to match the namespace ( case sensitive ). This might be a guess, but I just went into a MVC I use and changed the folder name and the namespace broke.